# Best approach to do Create, Read, Update, Delete operation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datatable, crud

While I try to learn CRUD operation (Create, Read, Update, Delete) in ASP.NET MVC, there are three different approaches to do CRUD operation in YouTube tutorials like

1. CRUD operation using Datatable
2. CRUD operation using JSON
3. CRUD operation using Stored Procedures.

I confuse a bit to know which is preferred way to do CRUD Operation.

Comment: Learn all the three methods :)

Comment: Is there any pros and cons in these methods @ssilas777

Comment: There should other different ways also to insert data into backed. Instead of focusing to one way, try to understand how each of this ways are working. You will learn eventually. Regarding cons and pros each developer would have their on interests based on their experience and project requirements.